# Curl and Grep to Parsing Content

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, grep, curl

I need to parse the output of a `curl` command:

```
curl --user test:test http://192.168.1.1/security/pkm.html | egrep '@company|config.pkm.password'
```

This returns:

```html
<input type="text" id="config.pkm.dentity" name="config.pkm.identity" value="00259E951451@company.net" maxlength="64" />
<input type="text" id="config.pkm.inner_identity" name="config.pkm.inner_identity" value="test@company.net" maxlength="64" />
<input type="password" id="config.pkm.password" name="config.pkm.password" value="382738" maxlength="64" />
```

I want to search for `name="config.pkm.identity"` and print `00259E951451@company.net`, for `name="config.pkm.inner_identity"` and print `test@company.net`, and for `name="config.pkm.password"` and print `382738`

Grep outputs just `00259E951451@company.net`, `test@company.net` and `382738`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/137158

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should use a HTML parser for this, but a (fragile) Awk solution would be:

```
 awk -F'"' '/pkm.identity/ {id = $8}; /inner_/ {inner = $8}; /password/ {pass = $8} END {print id" "inner" "pass}' file
 00259E951451@company.net test@company.net 382738
```

Comment: Awk result is : 00259e9517a5@company.net test@company.net  no password

Comment: @MehranGoudarzi Then the output that you included in your question is wrong...

Comment: i Replace /password/ with /pkm.password/  And now fixed .

Answer (score 0):

To grab information in the way of query you should use regex *capture groups* which are absent in `grep`. So try to filter out the `curl` output with `sed` (or `awk`) command:

```
sed -n 's/.*name="config.pkm.identity" value="\(.[^"]*\)".*$/\1/p'
```

where value of the field *value* is captured in `\1` (regex capture group #1). This will output the value of *name* field is `config.pkm.identity`.

For *name* is `config.pkm.password` use:

```
sed -n 's/.*name="config.pkm.password" value="\(.[^"]*\)".*$/\1/p'
```

and etc.

To show all available values of corresponding names just use:

```
sed -n 's/.*name=".*" value="\(.[^"]*\)".*$/\1</p'
```

**UPDATE** for comment

To make choice of the matching values in a sed's query use the following scheme:
Use additional regex grouping with `|` pipe sign which means `OR` statement. That allows `sed` to make choice from given set of variants to match final results (also note to escape both `|` pipe sign and `(` `)` parentheses)

For example:

```
sed -n -e 's/.*name="\(config.pkm.identity\|config.pkm.inner_identity\|config.pkm.password\)" value="\(.[^"]*\)".*$/\2/p'
```

this will search and output data for `config.pkm.identity`, `config.pkm.inner_identity` and `config.pkm.password` names in the stream.

Note also that the final regex capture group reference is `\2` - it is the second group now.

Comment: i cant use last sed you provide cause i have many names on my curl and i just want 3 of themes , how can i use 2 sed you provided in one command ?